# Exporting strings in Table format

Tags: list-manipulation, export, output-formatting

I have this code:

```
fortranFormDP[x_] := 
  NumberForm[x, {17, 16}, 
   NumberFormat -> (StringJoin[{#1, "d", #3} /. 
        "d" :> "d0" /; #3 == ""] &)];
normals={{-0.14609, -0.0840416, 0.985695}, {-0.213989, 0.112374, 
  0.970351}, {-0.147526, -0.00175264, 0.989057}};
data1 = fortranFormDP /@ normals
```

My goal is to export the `List` `data1` to a file in a `"Table"` format. Apparently, it is not straightforward as:

```
Export["myfile", data1]
```

because this produces:

```
{-0.1460901681201728d0, -0.0840415712588872d0, 0.9856950223466470d0}
{-0.2139894236453848d0, 0.1123736099765570d0, 0.9703508119998420d0}
{-0.1475262293814966d0, -0.0017526366367021d0, 0.9890565908527670d0}
```

Which is definitely not `"Table"` format. Although I did not find it anywhere, it looks like that `Mathematica` is unable to generate `"Table"` format from strings. What would probably work is to convert each sublist to one string separated by spaces or tabs. But there is a problem, if I do:

```
StringJoin/@data1
```

I get errors. (My plan was to do `StringJoin[Riffle[data1," "]]`). The source of the errors is probably due to `data1//FullForm`. I tried:

```
StringJoin/@(Evaluate@data1)
```

but it does not help.
How would I force evaluation of `data1`? And is there an easier way to export `"Table"` format if the data is strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is `NumberForm` is *not a string* .. here I've added `ToString`

```
fortranFormDP[x_] := 
  ToString@NumberForm[x, {17, 16}, 
    NumberFormat -> (StringJoin[{#1, "d", #3} /. 
         "d" :> "d0" /; #3 == ""] &)];
normals = {{-0.14609, -0.0840416, 0.985695}, {-0.213989, 0.112374, 
    0.970351}, {-0.147526, -0.00175264, 0.989057}};
```

now we need to take care to apply to individual numbers, and also specify "Table" on the `Export`

```
data1 = Map[fortranFormDP, normals, {2}]
Export["test.txt", data1, "Table"]
```

you can also do `SetAttributes[fortranFormDP, Listable]` , then use your original form:

```
data1 = fortranFormDP /@ normals
```

or even `data1 = fortranFormDP@normals`